# How can I disassemble an Android dex file within Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, disassembly, dex

I want to disassemble and view the contents of an Android dex file within Eclipse.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Right click on the project name in the package explorer.
2. Select the `Android Tools` sub menu.
3. Select `Display dex bytecode`.

The disassembled output will open in a new Eclipse text editor window.